# Binding properties from CustomControl to page in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, custom-controls

I want to bind properties from CustomControl to my page, then back to CustomControl and calculate quantity of pages and display it in list. 
My code look like.

CustomControl

```
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl

public CustomControl()
{
    InitializeComponent()
}
public int PageSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(PageSelectedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PageSelectedProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PageSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PageSelected", typeof(int), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));


 public int RecordsPerPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(RecordsPerPageProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(RecordsPerPageProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RecordsPerPageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RecordsPerPage", typeof(int), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

 public IList<int> RecordsPerPageList
        {
            get
            {
                return (IList<int>)GetValue(RecordsPerPageListProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(RecordsPerPageListProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RecordsPerPageListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RecordsPerPageList", typeof(List<int>), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public int RecordsCount
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(RecordsCountProperty);
            }
            set
            {

                SetValue(RecordsCountProperty, value);
                CreatePagesList();
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RecordsCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RecordsCount", typeof(int), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

 public IList<int> PagesList
        {
            get
            {
                return (IList<int>)GetValue(PagesListProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(PagesListProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PagesListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PagesList", typeof(List<int>), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

  public int PagesCount
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(PagesCountProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(PagesCountProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PagesCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PagesCount", typeof(int), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Custom Control xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Mtrx.CustomControls.CustomControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="90" Width="200">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>


        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="90" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <ComboBox Width="40" Height="20" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=PagesList}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=PageSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>


        <ComboBox Width="40" Height="20" Grid.Column="9" Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=RecordsPerPageList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=RecordsPerPage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>


    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Page xaml.cs

```
public class PageVievModel:AbstractPage

   public int RowsCount
        {
            get
            {
                return _rowsCount;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _rowsCount)
                {
                    _rowsCount = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("RowsCount");
                }
            }
        }
        private int _rowsCount; //we get it from other place
   public int DGRecordsMax
        {
            get
            {
                return _dgRecordsMax;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _dgRecordsMax)
                {
                    _dgRecordsMax = value;
                    if (value > 0)
                    {
                        DataGridRecordsMaxCount = value.ToString();
                        Settings.Default.Save();
                    }

                    RaisePropertyChanged("DGRecordsMax");
                }
            }
        }
        private int _dgRecordsMax;

        public IList<int> DGRecordsMaxList
        {
            get
            {
                return _dGRecordsMaxList;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_dGRecordsMaxList != value)
                {
                    _dGRecordsMaxList = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("DGRecordsMaxList");
                }
            }
        }
        private IList<int> _dGRecordsMaxList = new List<int>();

        public IList<int> PagesList
        {
            get
            {
                return _pagesList;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_pagesList != value)
                {
                    _pagesList = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("PagesList");
                }
            }
        }
        private IList<int> _pagesList = new List<int>();

        public int PagesCount
        {
            get
            {
                return _pagesCount;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _pagesCount)
                {
                    _pagesCount = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("PagesCount");
                }
            }
        }
        private int _pagesCount;

  public IList<int> CurrentPageList
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentPageList;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_currentPageList != value)
                {
                    _currentPageList = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentPageList");
                }
            }
        }
        private IList<int> _currentPageList;
```

Page xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeClass"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="800"
             IsEnabled="{Binding AllowInput, Converter={StaticResource AnyToBooleanConverter}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <DockPanel>

            <SomeClass:CustomControl Width="280" Height="190" 

                RecordsCount="{Binding RowsCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                RecordsPerPage="{Binding DGRecordsMax, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay }"
                RecordsPerPageList="{Binding DGRecordsMaxList, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                PagesCount="{Binding PagesCount, Mode=TwoWay}"
                PageSelected="{Binding CurrentPage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                PagesList="{Binding PagesList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                RecordsFrom="{Binding RecordsFrom, Mode=TwoWay}"
                RecordsTo="{Binding RecordsTo, Mode=TwoWay}"

                DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

            </WrapPanel.Resources>

        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I am trying to run my program there are empty lists, earlier when I just kept more properties in Page it was working fine.

I would be greatful for help. It's hard to understand for me how make this two way bindable properties.

Comment: Please provide a useful example. Currently you are using the type DataGridRecordsCounter for dependency property registration inside CustomControl. Please show the types you actually have, and only those. There is also no declaration for the PageSelected property in CustomControl.

Comment: I edited this, sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Are there any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you run the application in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, there is message "The specified value cannot be assinged. The following type was expected:"Object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make an example using your code.

For me it worked if I changed both IList and List to ObservableCollection, e.g.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
....

public ObservableCollection<int> PagesList
{
  get
  {
    return (ObservableCollection<int>)GetValue ( PagesListProperty );
  }
  set
  {
    SetValue ( PagesListProperty, value );
  }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty PagesListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PagesList", typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Note that I changed both the Property definition and the DependencyProperty definition.

Your code is a bit messy, for example you have a DockPanel tag which is closed with /WrapPanel, which obviously will not compile.

```
<DockPanel>
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about that I just cutted a part of code, because there was no sence to copy everything above.